# Why is pointer of 2d matrix different once using structure?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, pointers

I'm getting the same memory allocations for the first 2 printf's but the third returns different ones.
Can you help me figure out why?
Aren't they supposed to be the same?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 4

int main()
{
    
    typedef float mat [SIZE][SIZE];

    mat MAT_A,MAT_B,MAT_C,MAT_D,MAT_E,MAT_F;

    /*Used for going over MATs*/

    struct {
        char *name;
        mat *matrix;
    } mats[]={{"MAT_A",&MAT_A},
          {"MAT_B",&MAT_B},
          {"MAT_C",&MAT_C},
          {"MAT_D",&MAT_D},
          {"MAT_E",&MAT_E},
          {"MAT_F",&MAT_F},
          {"#",NULL}};

    printf("\n%p,%p",&MAT_A,mats[0].matrix[0][0]);
    printf("\n%p,%p",&MAT_A[0],mats[0].matrix[0]);
    printf("\n%p,%p",&MAT_A[1][0],mats[0].matrix[1][0]);
}
```

Here are the outputs:

[image]

Comment: `MAT_A[1][0]` is a different element than `MAT_A[0]`, why would you expect their addresses to be the same?

Comment: first is taking address, second is value

Comment: because `MAT_A` is `*mats[0].matrix`. `&MAT_A[1][0]` is not `(&MAT_A)[1][0]`, it's `&(MAT_A[1][0])`. To get consistent results use `(&MAT_A)[1][0]` or `&(*mats[0].matrix)[1][0]`. It's not left-to-right - & has precedence over []

Comment: @user253751 This solved it for me. Thank you so much!
Are you able to explain the difference between 
&(*mats[0].matrix)[1][0]
vs
mats[0].matrix[1][0]
?

Comment: @Niv you can probably work it out by yourself

Answer (score 2):

Your member variable `matrix` is a `float (*)[4][4]`, i.e. a pointer to an array of 4 times 4 `float` elements. When you deference, say, `mat[0].matrix` you get a l-value reference to `MAT_A`, which you can then use to access `MAT_A`'s `r`-th row and `c`-th column like this:

```cpp
(*mat[0].matrix)[r][c]
```

In C and C++, given a pointer `p`, accessing its `i`-th element through the index operator (i.e. `p[i]`) is the same as deferencing the `i`-th element after `p` (i.e. `*(p + i)`).
So, back to your code:

- `mats[0].matrix[0]` is the same as `*mats[0].matrix`;
- and `mats[0].matrix[1]` is the same as `*(mats[0].matrix + 1)`, which is *undefined behavior*.

If you want to print out the address of element `(1,0)` of `MAT_A` and the address of the second row of the array pointed to by `mats[0].matrix`, you may do it like this

```cpp
printf("\n%p,%p", &MAT_A[1][0], mats[0].matrix[0][1])
```

or:

```cpp
printf("\n%p,%p", &MAT_A[1][0], (*mats[0].matrix)[1]);
```

Comment: So did I get it right that mats[0].matrix is a pointer to the pointer of MAT_A?
Which means that (*mats[0].matrix ) provides us with the pointer of MAT_A itself?

Comment: `mats[0].matrix` is a pointer to `MAT_A`. So, deferencing it will return a l-value reference to `MAT_A`, which you can use to access its `r`-th row and `c`-th column like this: `(*mat[0].matrix)[r][c]`.

Comment: (dereferencing means using `*`)